# Django - How to organize pieces of code that I use all across the project?

Tags: django, helper

I'm new to Django. I have come from PHP, from CodeIgniter and in CodeIgniter we have thye concept of Helpers(functions that we use all across the project). I'm new to Python and I don't know the best way of doing this, I end up with this models.py:

```
from django.db import models
import unicodedata


class JobsadsText(models.Model):
    hash = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    site_name = models.TextField()
    uri = models.TextField()
    job_title = models.TextField()
    job_description = models.TextField()
    country_ad = models.TextField()
    zone_ad = models.TextField()
    location_ad = models.TextField()
    date_inserted = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
    db_table = u'jobsads_text'
    managed = False

    def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/frame/" + format_string_to_uri(self.zone_ad) + "/" + format_string_to_uri(self.location_ad) + "/" + format_string_to_uri(self.job_title) + ".html"

    def ascii_job_title(self):
    return strip_accents(self.job_title)

    def ascii_job_description(self):
    return strip_accents(self.job_description)

    def ascii_country_ad(self):
    return strip_accents(self.country_ad)

    def ascii_zone_ad(self):
    return strip_accents(self.zone_ad)

    def ascii_location_ad(self):
    return strip_accents(self.location_ad)
    # Para poder pesquisar palavras sem acentos - END -

    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.job_title


# H E L P E R S
# Para remover acentos de palavras acentuadas
def strip_accents( text, encoding='ASCII'):
    return ''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', unicode(text)) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn') )

'''
Esta funcao formata uma string para poder ser usada num URI
'''
def format_string_to_uri(string):
    # Para substituir os caracteres q nao sao permitidos no URL
    replacements = {"(" : "(", ")" : ")", "!" : "-", "$" : "-", "?" : "-", ":" : "-", " " : "-", "," : "-", "&" : "-", "+" : "-", "-" : "-", "/" : "-", "." : "-", "*" : "-",}
    return _strtr(_strip_accents(string).lower(), replacements)

# Para substituir occorrencias num dicionario
def _strtr(text, dic): 
    """ Replace in 'text' all occurences of any key in the given
    dictionary by its corresponding value.  Returns the new tring.""" 
    # http://code.activestate.com/recipes/81330/
    # Create a regular expression  from the dictionary keys
    import re
    regex = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(map(re.escape, dic.keys())))
    # For each match, look-up corresponding value in dictionary
    return regex.sub(lambda mo: str(dic[mo.string[mo.start():mo.end()]]), text)

# Para remover acentos de palavras acentuadas
def _strip_accents( text, encoding='ASCII'):
    return ''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', unicode(text)) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn') )
```

I use this functions(strip_accents, format_string_to_uri, _strtr, _strip_accents) all across the project. How can I organize this functions in a way that I have not to write this functions in every *.py file that I need to use them?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention is to create an utils.py module in your application and write there all of your helpers, also if you have some application which is not reusable at all, somthing specially tailored to your project the convention is to call it 'core' and put your adhoc code in there